# SQL LEFT JOIN with conditions reading either blank or last entry

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, left-join

I am trying to write a query that will take each asset row and fill in either blank for no last audit date or the last audit date if multiple audits exist for this asset. Two tables are below; the first for assets and the second for audits performed.

There are two additional left joins in the query with two other tables, but they are straight one-to-one attribute mappings and work fine as you can see in the array result below.

```
CREATE TABLE `asset_audit` (
    `audit_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
    `audit_asset_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `audit_date` date NOT NULL,
    `audit_present` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `audit_repairs` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `audit_comment` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `asset` (
    `asset_id` int(32) NOT NULL,
    `type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `supplier` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `asset_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `asset_desc` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `qty` int(32) NOT NULL,
    `serial` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `gcyo_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `purch_date` date NOT NULL,
    `purc_price` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `invoice_num` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `asset_image` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `asset_audit` (`audit_id`, `audit_asset_id`, `audit_date`, `audit_present`, `audit_repairs`, `audit_comment`) VALUES
(1, '1', '2023-03-01', '1', '0', 'this was the second audit of this piano, what a fine piano it is'),
(2, '1', '2023-02-01', '1', '0', 'this is the first audit date'),
(3, '1', '2023-04-04', '1', '0', 'these are the comments'),
(4, '1', '2023-04-04', '1', '1', 'repairs required'),
(5, '1', '2023-04-04', '0', '0', 'not in stock'),
(9, '3', '2023-04-02', '1', '0', 'this is the second asset');

INSERT INTO `asset` (`asset_id`, `type`, `supplier`, `asset_name`, `asset_desc`, `qty`, `serial`, `gcyo_id`, `purch_date`, `purc_price`, `invoice_num`, `asset_image`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1', 'Grand Piano', 'big piano on wheels', 1, '222333', '1001', '2023-04-03', '13,000.65', '1420TY445', 'images/1_Grand Piano.png'),
(3, '9', '3', 'Camera', 'avkans camera', 1, '22233333', '1004', '2023-03-28', '1,200.00', '1420TY44533', '');
```

This is the guts of the query I have been trying to get running.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM asset 
  LEFT JOIN asset_type ON asset.type = asset_type.asset_type_id 
  LEFT JOIN suppliers ON asset.supplier = suppliers.supplier_id 
  LEFT JOIN asset_audit ON asset.asset_id = asset_audit.audit_asset_id 
  WHERE
      asset_audit.audit_id = (
          SELECT MAX(audit_id)
          FROM asset_audit
          WHERE asset.asset_id = asset_audit.audit_asset_id
          )
  ORDER BY asset.type ASC, asset.asset_name ASC";
```

My code to query then fills a table (there is a bunch of other code of this page, this is the subsection performing this piece I am having trouble with (this is the snippet from phpize showing a single result). It should be showing a row for each asset listed. One asset has not had an audit so the audit date is blank; the other asset has had multiple audits so it should show the last audit date.

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 31
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)
```

This is the resulting array. It only contains a single response, and the last audit date is correct for that response, but there is no response in the array for the second asset. I have tried with an audit entry for the second asset, and no audit entry for the second asset; it has the same issue, it only brings back data for the first asset.

```
Array
(
    [asset_id] => 1
    [type] => 1
    [supplier] => 1
    [asset_name] => Grand Piano
    [asset_desc] => big piano on wheels
    [qty] => 1
    [serial] => 222333
    [gcyo_id] => 1001
    [purch_date] => 2023-04-03
    [purc_price] => 13,000.65
    [invoice_num] => 1420TY445
    [asset_image] => images/1_Grand Piano.png
    [asset_type_id] => 1
    [asset_type] => Percussion
    [asset_sub_type] => Tuned Percussion
    [supplier_id] => 1
    [supplier_name] => Piano Supplier 
    [supplier_add_line_1] => line 1
    [supplier_add_line_2] => line 2
    [supplier_suburb] => suburb
    [supplier_postcode] => 2321
    [supplier_state] => state
    [supplier_phone] => 2034956857
    [supplier_contact_name] => Peter supplier
    [supplier_notes] => this is /  some %notes# about"" the  'man
    [audit_id] => 8
    [audit_asset_id] => 1
    [audit_date] => 2023-04-04
    [audit_present] => 1
    [audit_repairs] => 0
    [audit_comment] => this was the second audit of this piano, what a fine piano it is
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an OR condition to the WHERE clause for the last LEFT JOIN. (The WHERE with OR applies to the LEFT JOIN only.)

```sql
SELECT * FROM asset 
LEFT JOIN asset_type ON asset.type = asset_type.asset_type_id 
LEFT JOIN suppliers ON asset.supplier = suppliers.supplier_id 
LEFT JOIN asset_audit ON asset.asset_id = asset_audit.audit_asset_id 
WHERE asset_audit.audit_id = (
    SELECT MAX(asset_audit.audit_id)
    FROM asset_audit
    WHERE asset.asset_id = asset_audit.audit_asset_id
)
OR asset_audit.audit_id IS NULL
ORDER BY asset.type ASC, asset.asset_name ASC
```

Comment: The outer where is applied to the result of the last left join, but that's the result of the sequence of joins in the from, so it's not clear why you are saying "The WHERE with OR applies to the LEFT JOIN only".